# Verify content of pdf with Zabbix web monitoring

Tags: zabbix

Is there any way to verify the content of pdf file in the step of Zabbix web scenario?
I need to compare text in pdf with variable from the previous step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use the `Required string` parameter with HTML content only and with some limitations, from the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/web_monitoring):

> Required regular expression pattern. Unless retrieved content (HTML)
>   matches the required pattern the step will fail. If empty, no check on
>   required string is performed. For example: Homepage of Zabbix
>   Welcome.*admin Note: Referencing regular expressions created in the
>   Zabbix frontend is not supported in this field.

The behavior, based on libcurl, is almost the same with the native [http agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/http), I think that you have to use an external script to download, parse/render and extract text from the pdf.

Comment: I don't use "required string", it usually doesn't work correctly. I use the {test} variable and regular expression pattern to verify the content.

Comment: Is there any way to use Apache tika with Zabbix

Comment: Ok, but the regexp can match a body response in html/json, not in a PDF because it's using libcurl.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Apache Tika